How to return a reference from iterator function?
I'd like to create an iterator from a function, which would yield references to a mutable variable.
Is this even possible in safe Rust?
code example in rust playground
which results in

error: captured variable cannot escape FnMut closure body

I did only worked around this issue when instead of a reference, a cloned variable is returned.
Is there some other, less expensive way?

A mutable reference? Because in your snippet that's a shared ref.

@ChayimFriedman Yes, shared reference to a mutable variable. My bad.

This isn't possible because a consumer of your iterator could hold an item reference while the iterator is advanced and the captured variable is mutated, thus invalidating all previously yielded references.  For example imagine that upon advancing the iterator, further items are pushed onto the vector causing it to reallocate or that the vector is cleared: either way, any previously yielded references would then be to freed memory.

It's hard to say without knowing exactly why you want to do this, but perhaps you're after something like streaming-iterator.

@eggyal Hmm, it sounds logical underlay variable can be mutated in-between and invalidate original reference. I thought about some concurrency access restriction means like Arc or Mutex could help here?

@eggyal In this case I need to create combinations generator/iterator of k-th order passed as an initial argument, to be conveniently used in iterator consumers like for loops.

res inside the function creates a Vec. However this is dropped by the end of the function, so returning a reference to it doesn't make much sense. But I'm not quite sure what you're trying to do :)

@Aldo'xoen'Giambelluca I'm trying to define function which returns an iterator over a variable created within that function (captured in a closure). So the only option is to move that variable in a result value? Or its cloned value?
